# word-wrap does not work in IE

Tags: css

Word-wrap as follows:

```
    /* The Breakage of Too Long Words */

div.break_word {
    width: 690px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

does wrap the word for the following table, but it also keeps the table stretched:

I used it in this portion of the table:

```
        <!--  The Contribution Description -->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><div class="break_word"><p><?php echo $contribution_description; ?></p></div></td>
        </tr>

        <!--  The Separation Line -->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>

        <!--  The Contribution -->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><pre><div class="break_word"><?php echo $contribution; ?></div></pre></td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

Does it keep it stretched, because it is overall a table and not a div? Or for which reason does it not stretch back, because the word is indeed wrapped.

Comment: Have you tried putting `word-wrap:` on the `<p>` inside the `<div>`?

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference as both p and div are block elements and thus treated the same.

Comment: as far as i can see, it's just ie7+table that gives trouble. if you replace table with fixed-width div, the div won't stretch

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As word-wrap is a CSS3 property, it is only supported by IE9 and higher. For IE8 try

```
-ms-word-wrap
```

So try

```
div.break_word {
    width: 690px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

It seems that even if you use -ms-word-wrap in IE7, it defaults the white-space: nowrap; which then overrides the word-wrap property.

Once again a IE hack is required. Try adding this for IE7.

```
white-space: normal;
```

Comment: it works fine in ie7-9 - it's just ie7 that's a bit too stupid to understand that the width of the parent element shouldn't expand.

Answer (score 0):

Your p within div works fine even in IE6.  Your div within pre is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Word wrap can be implemented for IE in the following way as well:

```css
div {
  max-width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongword</div>
<div>long long long long long long long word</div>
```