# How to avoid the text cross the div element in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I add the card to the in box. Then it is possible to double click on the card, and dialog pop up. In the dialog it is possible to create dynamic checkBoxes.

The issue is when I write some text, the text cross the div element. I don't want that. How can I avoid that?

You can see the problem in the image below:
[image]

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    // Click function to add a card
    var $div = $('<div />').addClass('sortable-div');

    var cnt = 0,
        $currentTarget;
    $('#AddCardBtn').click(function () {
        var $newDiv = $div.clone(true);
        cnt++;
        $newDiv.prop("id", "div" + cnt);

        $newDiv.data('checkboxes', []);

        $('#userAddedCard').append($newDiv);
        //      alert($('#userAddedCard').find("div.sortable-div").length);        
    });

    // Double click to open Modal Dialog Window
    $('#userAddedCard').dblclick(function (e) {
        $currentTarget = $(e.target);



        $('#modalDialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            height: 600,
            width: 500,
            position: 'center'
        });
        return false;

    });

    $("#Getbtn").on("click", function () {

        $('#modalDialog').dialog("close");
    });

    // Add a new checkBox
    $('#btnSaveCheckBox').click(function () {
        addCheckbox($('#checkBoxName').val());
        $('#checkBoxName').val("");
    });

    function addCheckbox(name, status) {
        status = status || false;

        var container = $('#boxs');
        var inputs = container.find('input');
        var id = inputs.length + 1;
        var data = {
            status: status,
            name: name
        };

        var div = $('<div />', { class: 'allcheckbox' });
        $('<input />', {
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 'cb' + id,
            value: name
        }).prop('checked', status).on('change', function () {
            data.status = $(this).prop('checked');
        }).appendTo(div); /* set checkbox status and monitor changes */

        $('<label />', {
            'for': 'cb' + id,
            text: name
        }).appendTo(div);

        div.appendTo(container);


    }

});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/131/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these answers:

[word-wrap does not work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357689/word-wrap-does-not-work-in-ie)

[word-wrap:break-word not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997223/word-wrapbreak-word-not-working-in-ie8)

Basically you do:

```
div.break_word {
    width: 690px; /* whatever width, if needed */
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal; 
}
```

Related:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Answer (score 3):

Either you can use CSS3 `overflow-wrap:break-word` property, `word-break: break-all`, or use `overflow-x:hidden` of your container element.

More information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap), [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap).

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.allcheckbox label
{
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This is forcing overflowing strings to break. Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/132/

Answer (score 1):

you can use css for this div

```
word-wrap:break-word;
overflow:hidden;
```